# How to write SQL query using sample tables and output

Tags: java, mysql, spring

This is the structure of my tables:

**table1**

```
id count
1  5
2  10
3  5
```

**table2**

```
id t1refid amount teamid
1   1       2     1
2   1       3     1
3   1       5     2
4   2       2     1
5   2       3     2
6   2       4     2
7   3       2     1
8   3       4     1
9   3       2     2
```

Following there are is expected output:

**output**

```
sum(transcount) sum(amount) teamid
  15                13       1
  15                14       2
```

How to generate sql query?

Comment: "How to will generate sql query" -- By writing it... speaking of which, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, you tagged this as Java and Spring. What does that have to do with creating a sql query?